# python multiple for loop question (pandas, dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
idx_list = []
for idx, row in df_quries_copy.iterrows():
    for brand in brand_name:
        if row['user_query'].contains(brand):
            idx_list.append(idx)
        else:
            continue
```

brand_name list looks like below

```
brand_name = ['Apple', 'Lenovo', Samsung', ... ]
```

I have df_queries data frame which has the query the user used
the table is looks like below

| user_query | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| Apple Laptop | A |
| Lenovo 5GB | B |

and also I have a brand name as a list
i want to find out the users who uses related with brand such as 'Apple laptop'

but when I run the script, I got a message saying that
**'str' object has no attribute 'contains'**

how am I supposed to do to use multiple for loop ?

Thank you in advance.

---

```
for brand in brand_name[:100]:
if len(copy_df[copy_df['user_query'].str.contains(brand)]) >0:
    ls.append(copy_df[copy_df['user_query'].str.contains(brand)].index)
    
else:continue
```

I tried like answer but the whole dataframe came out in a sudden as a result
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df_quries_copy[df_quries_copy['user_query'].str.contrains(brand)].index` to get index directly.

```py
for brand in brand_name:
    df_quries_copy[df_quries_copy['user_query'].str.contrains(brand)].index
```

Or in your code, use `brand in row['user_query']` since `row['user_query']` is a string value.

Comment: I have a quick question. no need to use iterrows to iterate the row of dataframe? I don't understand the logic even though the script is running :) and also i got a error unbalanced parenthesis at position 4

Comment: @Nini Yes, no need to iterate the dataframe. The `unbalanced parenthesis` might be some parenthesis is not closed.

Comment: yes, you can just put the condition what you want to filter like this, df[condition], you can read this too https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html

Comment: for brand in brand_name[:100]:
    print(copy_df[copy_df['user_query'].str.contains(brand)].index) 

the result is like below

Comment: Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
            17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
            34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
            51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
            68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84,
            85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99],
           dtype='int64')

Comment: @Nini What do you expect? If you want to turn it into list, use `df.index.tolist()`

Comment: I want to get the list but the result seems weird. eventually whole dataframe just came out as a result

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh please refer to the question I edited now

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Oh i think the data has an error. I will try again! THanks

Comment: @Nini Viewing your result pic, It seems that all your column value contains a same brand.